# Optional WHERE IN in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

I need a stored procedure that updates one of my tables, which has millions of records. For simplicity's sake, let's say it only does `SET LastUpdated = GETUTCDATE()`. The stored procedure should be able to do the following things with the best performance possible.

- Update all records (no `WHERE`)
- Update 1 record (`WHERE [Id] = @Id`)
- Update *n* records (`WHERE [Id] IN (@IdCsv)`)

What's the best way of achieving this?

1. Should I create three separate stored procedures? This would make the stored procedures less manageable because I'd have to keep three stored procedures up to date instead of one. However if this gets me the best performance, I wouldn't mind having three stored procedures instead of one. But is this really the best option, performance wise? Three separate stored procedures would mean three separate query plans, right?
2. I could also put everything in a single stored procedure with a `nvarchar` parameter which contains the IDs, comma-separated. Then, combined with `EXEC` I could do this:
   `WHERE [Id] IN (' + @IdCsv + ')`. I can further improve this by omitting the where statement if @IdCsv is null. This solution is a lot more manageable, but does it perform well?
3. The last solution I could think of is using a table-valued parameter. The condition would look like this: `WHERE @IdTable IS NULL OR [Id] IN (SELECT [Id] FROM @IdTable)`. This solution is also a lot more manageable than the first, and it also avoids the use of `EXEC`. However, I can't help but feel this would perform the worst, even if this is the only solution that would lead to one consistent query plan. The WHERE condition in this one is a lot more complex than the others.

Comment: Single proc will do.3 is the best. where exists(SELECT [Id] FROM @IdTable).BTW what will you update when there is no where condition.Secondly these are just few steps toward optimization have to share table design and their datatype.Thirdly with what parameter you will update any column ?

Comment: build a block of dynamic sql and execute the SP that way

Comment: @KumarHarsh 1 The stored procedure should be able to update all records if no parameters were passed, that's why I mentioned having no where condition - every record gets updated then. 2 I'm specifically looking to optimize the stored procedure itself, the types and tables involved don't really matter here. 3 The actual update contains a subquery that aggregates child data and sets various columns on the table that is being updated.

Comment: yeah  dynamic Sql may help using sp_executesql but it depend upon full requirement.Also optimizing sub query etc is more important than what you have asked.

Comment: I would begin with `WHERE LastUpdated <> GETUTCDATE()`. I noticed lesser IO with this approach (my column was indexed). YMMV. Also, since it is a stored procedure then you can write three separate UPDATE statements and use CASE _statement_ to fire one of them depending on input.

Comment: @KumarHarsh sp_executesql **IS** dynamic sql.

Comment: For a consistent interface you can always use a TVP. The SP can then branch on whether the TVP is empty, has a single row or has multiple rows. Note that the `IN` clause supports a (vague) limited number of values. Using `EXISTS` instead avoids the issue. Other techniques, e.g. `INNER JOIN`, may also be applicable.

Comment: `WHERE @IdTable IS NULL` - a table valued parameter cannot be null. it should be `WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from @IdTable)` Also, [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose between **high maintainable code** or **high performance**.

Check the execution plan when you write a high maintainable code.

```
DECLARE @ID INT
SET @ID=NULL
DECLARE @IdTable TABLE(ID INT)

UPDATE Test
SET LastUpdated = GETDATE()
WHERE (ID = @ID OR @ID IS NULL)
OR EXISTS
(
 SELECT 1 FROM @IdTable T WHERE T.ID = ID
)
```

[image]

If you see the execution plan, a table scan is happening on `@IdTable` which is costing 25% of total execution cost. Definitely you can remove it by using a '#' temporary table with index on Id, but still it will be a overhead to the query.

When you want high performing query like following.

```
UPDATE Test
SET LastUpdated = GETDATE()
```

[image]

> I suggest you go with a single update, it should work fine if your ID
>   column is Indexed. SQL Server is optimized and  capable of handling
>   huge volumes of records.

Comment: I hadn't considered creating a stored procedure with both `@ID` and `@IdTable` parameters yet. It seems there's an issue with your implementation, if `@ID` is null all records will be updated regardless of the contents of `@IdTable`.

Comment: You are right, i didn't realized it. Will update soon

Comment: OPTION (RECOMPILE) is your friend here.  Also, with a bit flag you can completely eliminate the subquery if the @IdTable is empty...  IF EXISTS (Select * from @IdTable)  SET @usetable=1 ... and in the query ... AND ((@useTable = 0) OR id in (select ... from @IdTable))